# Should I use an alias or a wrapper for an Integer type ID?

Tags: wrapper

You have `n` lists, each serves as a global dictionary. Everything else is handled via IDs that represent the index in the appropriate list. Typically, this is some type of integer. However, trying to access index `i` in list `A` when it is meant for list `B` would result in nonsense at best or a crash at worst.

While I can use aliases `A_index = integer_type`, `B_index = integer_type` ... this does not prevent me from accidently plugging in the wrong index to a function, although it already improves readability of the code. If I write a custom type, say `struct A_index {integer_type id;};` it feels a bit cumbersome.

What are some general guidelines to this?

(While I think this is an agnostic problem, refer to C++ if needed)

Comment: The problem is that most languages like C++ do not have convenient facilities to implement newtypes. Your struct is a POD type which is good, but you'd want the ID to be private. But then you have to at least implement rule-of-three functions (like copy constructor and copy assignment) for the newtype to feel natural. The newtype pattern is much more convenient in Haskell or Rust though.

Comment: Is the number of lists (`n`) fixed throughout the lifetime of the project? Will the number of lists grow in the future?

Comment: Is this language specific? IMHO it should be for concrete implementations as it can vary wildly.

Comment: @rwong it is fixed.

Answer (score 4):

An old trick that works in C and C++: You declare a pointer to an incomplete type like this:

```
typedef struct whatever_a* index_a;
```

You never ever declare the struct. But you have a distinct type now that can hold the same information as intptr_t. Can’t interact with other ids. No arithmetic. Only operations are comparisons, and cast to and from integer (some compilers don’t like casting to/from int but only some integer type with as many bits as a struct pointer).

Answer (score 2):

If C# is applicable here, or presumably any other language with generic types, a neat trick is to make a generically typed class where the generic type is not really used in its implementation.

```
 public struct Key<TEntity> 
 {
       public int Value { get; set; }
 }
```

`TEntity` can then be your different list element types. `A` has a `Key<A>`, etc. It provides type safety and avoids having to define a key struct for each list.

However, I would personally still opt for concrete non-generic types, but with an inherited implementation.

```
 public struct Id<T> 
 {
       public T Value { get; set; }
 }

 public struct PersonId : Id<int> {}
```

Requires explicit types but feels cleaner in terms of having bounded contexts and more easily allows for more complex keys when needed. I also try to avoid generic type pollution as it can get a bit annoying after a while.